# Stata - Selective Sort

Tags: sorting, stata

In Stata, I want to sort only the first 10 observations (and leave observations 11 and above in their same original order).  How do I do this?  I tried:

```
sort column1 column2 if _n<11
```

But this does not seem to do the trick.  How should I think about this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **syntax** in `help sort` is clear:

```
sort varlist [in] [, stable]
```

You can use `in`, but not `if`. An example:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto
keep make price mpg

list in 1/10

*-----

sort price in 1/5

list in 1/10
```

`help <command>` is a basic resource available to you. (So you could now try `help in`, for more details.)